# How to check no element remained?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:-

```js
$("span").on('click', function() {
  if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  var remained_trs = $(this).closest("table").find("span");
  if (remained_trs.length < 1) {
    $('body').html('there is not any element');
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, when I remove one element *(there are still some other element)*, but `there is not any element` appears. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: since you removed the clicked span so `var remained_trs = $(this).closest("table").find("span");` this will be undefined, that's why not working

Comment: @AlivetoDie Oh! You are totally right .. good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you removed the clicked span so:-

`var remained_trs = $(this).closest("table").find("span");`

will be undefined (because `$(this)` is unrecognisable now), that's why code is not working.

Need to do like below:-

```js
$("span").on('click', function () {
   var table = $(this).closest("table");//get clicked span table and create it's object
  if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  } else {
      return false;
  }
  var remained_trs = table.find("span");
  if ( remained_trs.length < 1 ) {
      table.html('there is not any element'); // change html of corresponding table not the body
  }
});
```

```css
span{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Six</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Note:-Also instead of `$('body').html('there is not any element');` use `table.html('there is not any element');` (since you have multiple tables)***

Comment: I think it won't work. because there is multiple tables *(without any specific class or id)* in the page. So `table.find("span")` won't work correctly. I need a selector based on the clicked element (`$(this)`)

Comment: @stack  check now

Comment: @stack i have added two tables to make it more explanatory and visible what is happening.

Comment: @stack  also instead of `$('body').html('there is not any element');` use `table.html('there is not any element');` (since you have multiple tables).I have added that in my code

Answer (score 3):

When `$(this).closest("tr").remove();` executes the element is removed from DOM to scope of `this` is completely lost.

Store the reference of table before removing the row, then perform the remove operation.

```
var table = $(this).closest("table");
```

```js
$("span").on('click', function() {
  //Store the reference of table before removing the row.
  var table = $(this).closest("table");
  if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  var remained_trs = table.find("span");
  if (remained_trs.length < 1) {
    $('body').html('there is not any element');
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think it won't work. because there is multiple tables *(without any specific class or id)* in the page. So `table.find("span")` won't work correctly. I need a selector based on the clicked element (`$(this)`)

Comment: I have used `this` haven't you noticed? `var table = $(this).closest("table");`

Answer (score 2):

you are deleting current row before getting next thats why it happen

```js
$("span").on('click', function() {
  var nearTable = $(this).closest("table");
  if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  var remained_trs = nearTable.find("span");
  if (remained_trs.length < 1) {
    $('body').html('there is not any element');
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the parent element of the element you are clicking, so `$(this)` doesn't exist when you are trying to find the other `span`s. You need to cache the closest `table` by doing

```
var $closestTable = $(this).closest("table");
```

**DEMO**

```js
$("span").on('click', function() {
  var $closestTable = $(this).closest("table");
  if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  var remained_trs = $closestTable.find("span");
  if (remained_trs.length < 1) {
    $('body').html('there is not any element');
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td><span>×</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are deleting current row before getting next thats why it happen

```
$("span").on('click', function () {
       var table = $(this).closest("table");
      if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
          $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      } else {
          return false;
      }
      var remained_trs = table.find("span");
      if ( remained_trs.length < 1 ) {
          $('body').html('there is not any element');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check for table rows instead of the span you are deleting and referring to!

```js
$("span").on('click', function () {
                    if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
                        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var remained_trs = $('#table1 tr').length;
                   
                    if ( remained_trs < 1 ) {
                        $('body').html('there is not any element');
                    }
                })
```

```css
span{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td><span>×</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>two</td>
        <td><span>×</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>three</td>
        <td><span>×</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```